# Cookie management with jquery not working

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a simple application of cookie with jquery. I want that when a user logs in from a form on a jsp page. a cookie is generated storing the email entered in the form. Navigating to another page i am trying to access cookie and fill a textfield with the cookie value of email. But neither it seems that cookie is generated nor i am able to access the cookie.

My code of form:

```
<s:form id="login" action="login" method="post" cssClass="text">
                    <s:textfield id="email" name="email" label="Email address:"/>
                    <s:password name="pswd" label="Password :"/>
                    <s:submit value="Login"/>
                </s:form>
```

My script tag of form.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#login").submit(function() {
                        var email = $('#email').val();
                        $.cookie('email', email, { expires: 1 });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

My navigated page navigated.jsp is :

```
<s:textfield label="Your Email :" id="email" name="email"/>
```

and code of script in navigated.jsp is :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var email = $.cookie('email');
                $('#email').val(email);
            });
        </script>
```

Please point out what may b the problem..?

Comment: Why do you use the submit event to generate the cookie? Have you tried the simple way (Create a button, add the event onClick on it and call the function for generating the cookie)?

Comment: Obvious question: you are including the jQuery.cookie plugin, right?

Comment: Are `form.jsp` and `navigated.jsp` on the same path? By default, cookies are visible just to the "folder" level they are set in. `/signup/form.jsp` and `/profile/navigated.jsp` wouldn't work, for example.

Comment: @Spudley Yes of course i am using jquery.cookie plugin.. Is there any other way to achieve to cookie management using jquery..? Can i have your suggestions on above problem.

Comment: @pixelistik Yes all the pages and also the jquery plugin on the same path. Yet there is problem. Can you point out what can be the problem..?

Comment: @reporter Is there any problem you are looking in my submit even..? then plz let me know.  (However i am also trying to use the onClick event.)

Comment: @Rambo - yes, I thought you probably would have, but it's worth checking the obvious things! :-) Anyway, since you asked, I've posted an answer with an alternative option.

Comment: @Rambo Your problem can caused by a couple of side effects. Only the browser knows what he want to do. Yerify your cookie code is working correct you shouldn't use the submit event. Though I'm not sure that the browser executes your implemented in code. I think he submits the data first and ignores your code (As I said, I'm not sure).

Comment: Can some one help me on this problem as well..? thanks.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641662/doccookie-is-not-getting-saved-instantly

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the jQuery cookie plugin to work, you could try another library.

Cookie handling is fairly simpl.

The Mozilla Developer site has a full cookie library in only a few dozen lines of code - copy it from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am very new to jquery. Actually i am being very uncomfortable with  document.cookie. I will b really thankful if you post your full answer with the full codes replaced inside script tags in both the case (create and retrieve) according to document.cookie as you suggested.

Comment: @Rambo - the page linked has a full cut+paste class you can use that copy; gives you simple get/set functions.

Comment: "docCookies.setItem("email", document.login.email);
                alert(docCookies.getItem("email")); " I placed this inside the script tag within a function which is called when submit button is pressed. But i see in alert i have "[objectHTMLinputElement]" inside alert. how to fetch the email of the form to store in the cookie named "email"..? what is wrong here..?